# AKS k8s dotnet gRPC api begind nginx-ingress

Tags: .net, kubernetes, grpc, nginx-ingress, grpc-c#

I have a following setup:

- Web app
- Grpc api

Both deployed on k8s behind nginx-ingress with auto tls provided by cert-manager. When Web app is trying to reach the gRPC api i'm getting 404. The gRPC api is running on 80 without tls so the ingress should terminate SSL. Here is my ingress configuration:

**UPDATE:**

Requests coming through thanks to help of Mr. Mason. Now I am getting 403 PermissionDEnied response. Any ideas how this can be resolved ?

````
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: ${AUTH_API_IMAGE}
spec:
    type: ClusterIP
    ports:
    - port: 80 
    - targetPort: 5300
    selector:
        app: ${AUTH_API_IMAGE}
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ${AUTH_API_IMAGE}-ingress
  annotations:  
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPC"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - ${AUTH_API_HOST_NAME}
    secretName: ${AUTH_API_IMAGE}-tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: ${AUTH_API_HOST_NAME}
    http:
      paths: 
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: ${AUTH_API_IMAGE}
            port:
              number: 80```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you must use SSL if this is a dotnet, however below code works for me.

With addition of `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/grpc-backend: 'true'`
and changing PathType to `ImplementationSpecific`

````yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ${AUTH_API_IMAGE}-ingress
  annotations:  
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "GRPC"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/grpc-backend: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - ${AUTH_API_HOST_NAME}
    secretName: ${AUTH_API_IMAGE}-tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: ${AUTH_API_HOST_NAME}
    http:
      paths: 
      - path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: ${AUTH_API_IMAGE}
            port:
              number: 80```
````

and configMap for Ingress

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: ingress
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: >
      {"apiVersion":"v1","data":{"ssl-ciphers":"ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384"},"kind":"ConfigMap","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"nginx-ingress-controller","namespace":"ingress"}}
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/ingress/configmaps/nginx-ingress-controller
data:
  client-body-buffer-size: 32k
  client-header-buffer-size: 32k
  hsts: 'true'
  hsts-max-age: '31536000'
  hsts-preload: 'true'
  http2-max-field-size: 32k
  http2-max-header-size: 32k
  large-client-header-buffers: 32 32k
  proxy-buffer-size: 128k
```

Comment: thanks for a blazing fast reply ! we sem to be moving as now I'm getting 502 instead of 404 ! :) Do you know what can be wrong ?

Comment: If this helped to get the ingress passed, please mark this as answered, I will check your 502 logs to see what's wrong with that, can you create a new post and put the pod's logs to see what's going on in the pod.

Comment: Legend, thanks . I sorted that out but now getting 403 , will look into it :) Thanks

Comment: any idea what might be causing the 403 ?

Comment: 403 usually means unauthorized, are you authenticating user on the endpoint?

Comment: @Mason.Chase not sure how that works, but this annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/grpc-backend: 'true'` does not exist

Comment: two years has passed and I think the annotation may have changed. if you found the latest tag I will update the answer